# Azure Functions for Azure IoT Edge, Which Languages are Supported?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-edge

What is the status of Azure Functions for Azure IoT Edge?  Here its stated that only C# is supported https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-functions-2-0-available-in-iot-edge/

I cannot find documentation on whats the current state? Which Languages are supported now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status is still the same, only C# is supported. The latest information on this is probably [this Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/74110)